# Microk8s offline install without using snap?

Tags: software-installation, microk8s

I am trying to install Microk8s but for various reasons, we cannot use snap (mainly around the way how we start/stop services). To complicate things a bit more we do not often have internet access when we are doing the install.

Is there an alternative way to do so that is an offline install?

Comment: Same question.  Want to do an offline install and do not want to use snap.  I should not have to install a daemon (snapd) just to install software.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like no.

Source: https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/988 / https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives#heading--offline

Person who answered was a member of Canonical/Ubuntu, and I haven't seen any headway on this.